# How to use a delegate in unity to notify that firebase has retrieved a document

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I've got a firebasesript.cs file with a class of the same name and in Start I retrieve firebase docs. For each doc retrieved trying to get main.cs to be notified.

In firebasescript there's

```
public delegate void LoadDoc();
public static event LoadDoc onLoadDoc;
```

In main there's

```
void Start()
{

   firebasescript.onLoadDoc += DocLoaded;

}

void DocLoaded()
{
   Debug.Log("loaded");
}
```

Just don't know how to get the event to fire in firebasescript:

```
  foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in capitalQuerySnapshot.Documents) {
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", documentSnapshot.Id));
    Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city) {

**//here is where i want the notification to happen**

      Debug.Log(String.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }
  };
});
```

And if there's better ways to do this def open to all suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I would highly recommend reading [Microsoft's C# event documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/), including [how to publish events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines).

The TLDR is that you simply need to call `onLoadDoc();` in your firebasescript to raise the event. You'll also probably want to check for null in case:

```
if (onLoadDoc != null) {
    onLoadDoc();
}
```

You'll also want to unsubscribe from the listener in `OnDestroy`, otherwise there's a really good chance that you'll get a null reference exception with how [Unity Overrides null](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) and relies on underlying C++ logic (note that in a normal C# framework, this is still a memory leak even if it doesn't null out):

```
void OnDestroy() {
    firebasescript.onLoadDoc -= DocLoaded;
}
```

One other piece of advice is that if you're working in Unity, you probably want to use [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) rather than C# events. In my own testing, I found it marginally less performant. The upside is that it's aware of the Unity lifecycle (when objects go to null/when OnDestroy is called), you don't have to do the null check before invoking, and you can hook them up in the editor. This last bit is super useful when iterating on your game design or for enabling less technical members of your team.

You'd change the field declaration to look something like:

```
public UnityEvent OnLoadDoc = new UnityEvent();
```

You'd invoke it with:

```
OnLoadDoc.Invoke();
```

And you can add a listener with:

```
OnLoadDoc.AddListener(DocLoaded);
```

I've found that unsubscribing doesn't seem to be necessary with `UnityEvent`, but it's still good practice (and likely a bit of a performance boost):

```
OnLoadDoc.RemoveListener(DocLoaded);
```

One more thing I might suggest: you can use [UniRx](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx) to add reactive features to your Firebase game. I'm not the biggest reactive programming fan, but most of my coworkers are really into the pattern, and it gives you powerful features to control how events are built, aggregated, and dispatched.

--Patrick